# Positioning object to the center of camera view in 3D scene?

Tags: coordinates

How to position an object to the centre of camera’s viewport in the scene (for example position camera wherever you want and toggle preview of it by pressing NUMPAD 0). So basically position object to the centre relative to the preview camera viewport. Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify what is crosshair mesh? And what do you mean by "camera viewport"? Center of world (global) coordinates is 0,0,0 where you can put 3D cursor with Shift+S > Cursor to center

Comment: please clarify.  you can use align camera to view.... or align active camera to selected.... or many other options...

Comment: edited, should be clearer now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method centers the object's *origin* in the camera viewport. If you want to center the geometry position its origin at the center of mass first.<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>

The green circle indicates the desired position. The plane (perpendicular to the camera) indicates where the object is supposed to move.

[image]

1. Add a helper object (an empty) at the objects position.
   <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>select the object.
    <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > Cursor to selected.
     <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Empty.
   [image]
2. <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select the camera. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select the empty. Add a **Copy Rotation** constraint to the empty by pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > *Copy Rotation*.
   [image]
3. Snap the cursor to the camera.
   [image: Cursor at camera.]
4. Set the **Pivot Point** to *3D Cursor.*
   [image]
5. <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select the empty and scale it to zero along its local XY plane.
   <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> > <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> > <kbd>0</kbd>
   [image]
6. Snap the cursor the the empty, then the object to the cursor.
   [image]

Comment: Thats clever, and also a pain in the neck :D